# Making ffmpeg/javacv less verbose in java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javacv, verbosity

I have a Java application that uses `ffmpeg` library and `javacv` to load and process video files.

I am currently using following code, for loading `videofile` to my data container.

```
public boolean add(String videofile) {
        FrameGrabber g = new OpenCVFrameGrabber( videofile );
        try{ 
            g.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber( videofile );
            try {
                g.start();
            }catch(Exception x){
                return false;
            }
        }
        grabbers.add( new Pair(videofile, g) );
        frames.add( 0 );
        preprocessed=false;
        return true;        
    }
```

Each time video is loaded, a library outputs a lot of meta information regarding video itself:

> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/lejlot/data/test.mp4': 
>   Metadata:
>       major_brand     : isom
>       minor_version   : 512
>       compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
>       encoder         : Lavf53.21.1   Duration: 00:04:36.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 305 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 303 kb/s, 20,85
>   fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : VideoHandler

which obviously I do not want to see. I cannot (do not want) to modify the libraries source codes, but rather modify my own so it can intercept this log and discard it.

As far I tried to temporarly block the stdout/stderr streams through

```
private static final devnull = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b,int x,int y){
        }
   });

   /**
   * Blocks messages to stdout
   */
   public static void silentStdOut(){
     System.setOut(devnull);
   }

   /**
   * Blocks messages to stderr
   */
   public static void silentStdErr(){
     System.setErr(devnull);
   }
```

but it does not seem to help, log message is still displayed

```
public boolean add(String videofile) {
    Utils.silentStdErr();
    Utils.silentStdOut();
    FrameGrabber g = new OpenCVFrameGrabber( videofile );
    try{ 
        g.start();
    }
    ,,,
```

"Raw" ffmpeg can be set to be less verbose using

```
ffmpeg -loglevel panic
```

but neither `OpenCVFrameGrabber` not `FFmpegFrameGrabber` give access to the tool's parameters.

To sum up - how can I discard these log messages without modifing the libraries' source codes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

had the same problem a few minutes ago, and also looked on the net, nothing except your question. Then i started digging in the ffmpeg sources and found a solution, add the import:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avutil;
```

and then just call:

```
avutil.av_log_set_level(avutil.AV_LOG_QUIET);
```

before you create the FFmpegFrameGrabber -> No more messages form ffmpeg.

Regards
Daniel

Comment: this reminds me of http://xkcd.com/979/ . Thank you for this answer, works perfectly.

Comment: 2017 solution: It is now `import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil;`

Comment: This helped me a huge amount just now, THANK YOU!

Comment: 2023, now you need import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil;

Answer (score 5):

This is updated solution(w.r.t. javacv from github)

add the import statement given below

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil.AV_LOG_PANIC;  
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil.av_log_set_level;
```

call the below statement before you create the FFmpegFrameGrabber -> No more messages form ffmpeg.

```
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_PANIC);
```

Answer (score 2):

javacv v1.5.7, the `avutil` package is now located at `org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil`. The `av_log_set_level(...)` answer works exactly the same, the package just moved.